# Как сделать чтобы фигура не вылазила за рамку при трансформациях?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Пишу небольшое приложение на WPF. Нужно чтобы внутри рамки (Border) была фигура (например Rectangle), к которой можно было бы применять некие преобразования (например поворот на 30 градусов).
Всё получилось, но только вот при повороте фигуры, она выходит за границы рамки.
Как это исправить?

[image: Фигура вылезла за рамки]

```
partial class AbstractShape : Border
{
    public AbstractShape(in Shape shape)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Child = shape;
    }
}
```

В чём проблема, как видится мне: У фигуры по умолчанию стоит свойство Fill, т. е. заполнения всей доступной области, однако вместо того чтобы самой исказиться, она предпочитает вылезти за рамки.
Если я растяну после поворота фигуры саму рамку в высоту и ширину, то фигура соответственно тоже вновь изменит размер и опять выскочит.

Comment: не уверен но модет помоч уменшить  индекс по z оси у фигуры Panel.ZIndex

Comment: По умолчанию любой элемент позволяет "выползать" своему содержимому за свои приделы. Что бы изменить эту логику достаточно установить `ClipToBounds` в значение `True` у вашего `Border`'a, тогда все, что будет заходить за пределы этого элемента будет [обрезаться](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBpTv.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, А как сделать чтобы не обрезалось, а искажалось но вмещалось целиком?

Comment: масштабируйте тогда эелемент

Comment: Вообще есть 2 типа трансформации: `RenderTransform` и `LayoutTransform`. Выберите тот, который подходит вам

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ClipToBounds=true установил, не работает, даже не обрезает фигуру, все равно выходит за границы

Comment: Всё заработало! Спасибо @АндрейNOP и @EvgeniyZ! Действительно, ClipToBounds=true не работало пока я использовал RenderTransform, стоило заменить RenderTransform на LayoutTransform как всё заработало правильно, фигура стала аккуратно вписываться внутрь рамки, уменьшаясь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует 2 вида трансформаций:

- `RenderTrahsform` — трансформация применяется *после компоновки*, т. е. родительская панель (или контрол) сначала измеряет фигуру и выделяет ей место, а потом фигура трансформируется относительно этого места, поэтому она может выходить за пределы родителя;
- `LayoutTransform` — трансформация применяется *до компоновки*, т. е. сначала к фигуре применяется трансформация, а потом родительская панель (или контрол) измеряет уже трансформированную фигуру и выделяет ей место с учетом нового габарита, поэтому такие трансформации, как `TranslateTransform` могут вообще не вносить видимого результата.

Пример:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Brown" Margin="5">
        <Border Background="YellowGreen" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="30"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        </Border>
    </Border>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Brown" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1">
        <Border Background="YellowGreen" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="30"/>
            </Border.LayoutTransform>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло. Оказывается при использовании LayoutTransform устанавливать ClipToBounds не обязательно.

Comment: `ClipToBounds` — это вообще обрезка содержимого по границе родителя и к трансформациям имеет посредственное отношение.

Comment: Т.е. выставлять `ClipToBounds` надо именно у родителя, а не у содержимого.