# Поворачивается ли сам элемент при трансформации с помощью LayoutTransform?

Tags: c#, wpf

Все сводится к тому, что мне стало не понятно. что произошло с `Layout`'om элемента, после его поворота на `-90°`.

Т.е. при повороте через `RenderTransform`, сам элемент не поворачивается, и место для него резервируется ровно столько же, сколько `0°` *(ну или в горизонтальном положении)*.

Когда я повернул `Layout`, вроде бы повернулся сам элемент, но я в этом не уверен, т.к. в дизайнере, после написания `XAML`,и выделения этого элемента, я увидел следующий артефакт *(если это артефакт)*:

[image: Изображение]

И теперь стоит вопрос, это дизайнер показывает то что элемент повернут, или же место все так же резервируется для размещения в горизонтальном положении?

XAML:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="LeftSideMenuRegion">
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="CadetBlue">
                  <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="Unable to load plugin `Left Menu`."
                    Foreground="DarkSlateGray"
                    UseLayoutRounding="True"
                    TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Padding="5">
                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                      <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform />
                        <SkewTransform />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                        <TranslateTransform />
                      </TransformGroup>
                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                  </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947576/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Это конечно не то что я хотел, но как я понял из ответа написанного вами, т.е. он выделяет место для уже повернутого элемента, верно? И не стоит морочить голову над представлением в дизайнере?

Comment: Для LayoutTransform да, измерение происходит после трансформации. В дизайнере много глюков...